# How can I add new button to highlight text in this useful editor

Tags: jquery, text-editor

This is an example that I found http://jsbin.com/awituc/25/edit

the question is how to create a new button to add specific color maybe red to the selected text ?

Comment: why don't you use other, already built editors like jWYSIWYG,tinymce,fckeditor. all this editors already have the thing you wanted ...instead of reinventing the wheel... google text editor jquery and you;ll get tons of it...

Comment: i want to learn how to built my own .. so any help please ?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to built jQuery plugins from scratch. Nice video here: http://bit.ly/14dXuXL study it and you will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Sergej nice i will .. but actually i need a quick help now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
http://jsbin.com/awituc/230/edit

**Added code to plugin:** 
 Settings:

```
colors: [{ key: "Red", value: "#ff0000" },
         { key: "Green", value: "00ff00" },
         { key: "Blue", value: "#0000ff" }]
```

can be overridden when initiating plugin:

```
$("textarea").myTextEditor({ colors: [{ key: "yellow", value: "#ffff00" }] });
```

Dropdown:

```
var selectColor = $("<select/>", {
        data: {
            commandName: "ForeColor"
        },
        change: execCommand
    }).appendTo(buttonPane);
```

Code that sets color:

```
$.each(settings.colors, function (i, v) {
        $("<option/>", {
            value: v.value,
            text: v.key,
            style: "color:" + v.value
        }).appendTo(selectColor);

    });
```

**execCommand reference:** 
http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=879

**jQuery plugins tutorial:**
http://bit.ly/14dXuXL